# Dynamically adding views missing scrollbar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, dynamic

I am adding views dynamically like this:

```
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicabout, null);
            TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.aboutcontent);
            textOut.setText(strings.get(index));
            ((ViewGroup) v).addView(addView);
```

However, once we get to the bottom of the screen and beyond, there's no scrollbar.
I tried using the ScrollView, but that doesn't do anything.

dynamicabout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aboutcontent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

about.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/stdpadding"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linear
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/aboutcontent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="all"/>
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
LinearLayout linear=(LinearLayout)findviewbyId(R.id.linear);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
            (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dynamicabout, null);
            TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.aboutcontent);
            textOut.setText(strings.get(index));
linearview.addView(addView);
```

please chk this code:

Comment: My lazy side thanks you for writing it out for me :D

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is you need to have Parent and Child view. Add child to the Parent. Parent is LinearLayout in ScrollView in dynamicabout.xml. Child is about XML. Inflate about XML on the runtime and Add it into Parent View (LinearLayout in ScrollView).

P.S. > Set an ID for the Parent Layout in order to be able to add views inside it, as far as I see it doesn't have ID.